# Duplicate calendar entries presumably caused by Google's calendar sync

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calendar, google-calendar

I have a subscribed calendar in my Google account.

Events from this calendar get synced to my phone as you would expect. However, whenever it syncs it creates a completely new event instead of updating the existing one, or taking no action.

How can I fix this?

*Samsung Galaxy S running Gingerbread 2.3.6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling the linked calendar, and adding it manually using the ICalSync app in the market.